# Adding HTML Content after element

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

In a CMS I'm developing, the client wants a checkered bottom border underneath all the h2 elements. However, as they're dynamically set via a WYSIWYG editor, there's no way to create static place holders.

The checkered border is just a div with a preset height and width:

```
<div class="checkers-white-left"></div>
```

How can I add that after each  element? I've tried the CSS :after pseudo, but that didn't work, as I knew it wouldn't.

Short of modifying the data being sent and stored in the server, is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is generating the HTML? I'm assuming there's a PHP page that does that? if so, what's the code for it?

Comment: "i've tried the CSS :after pseudo, but that didn't work"...why not show us **that** code...! It's not entirely clear what a "checkered bottom border" would look like either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give all the elements a distinguishing class, so you can select them all. Then you can do:

```
$(".elementClass").after("<div class='checkers-white-left'/>");
```

Comment: All of the elements that have a border after them are of the same Class, so that will work perfectly, actually!